# windows phone 7 updating isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, insert, isolatedstorage, text-files

In windows phone 7, what is the protocol for updated an isolated storage text file? Say I have 10 words in a text file arranged at 1 per line. Now suppose, the user uses the application and a new word needs to be stored on the fifth line. How do I write to the file, which already contains 10 words with 1 word per line?

Thanks in advance you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have been doing it is:

1. Read in a file from IsolatedStorage to menmory
2. Update the String
3. Write the file back to storage

### Read in File

```
public static string ReadFromStorage(string filename)
{
    string fileText = "";
    try
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, storage)))
            {
                fileText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    catch
    {
    }

    return fileText;
}
```

### Write to File

```
public static void WriteToStorage(string filename, string text)
{
    try
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
            if (!storage.DirectoryExists(directory))
                storage.CreateDirectory(directory);

            if (storage.FileExists(filename))
            {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(filename + " Exists\nOverwrite Existing File?", "Question", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

                if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
                    return;
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(storage.CreateFile(filename)))
            {
                sw.Write(text);
            }
        }
    }

    catch
    {
    }
}
```

So I would do:

```
string fileName = "Test.txt";
string testFile = IsolatedStorage_Utility.ReadFromStorage(fileName);
testFile = testFile.Replace("a", "b");
IsolatedStorage_Utility.WriteToStorage(fileName, testFile);
```

Comment: So basically, you just overwrite the file each time?

Comment: It's just easier. This is how you do it on pretty much any operating system. Think of Windows; you read a file in, modify it, then rewrite the whole thing back. Technically you can modify only the parts you need if you know what to replace in advanced. Im also assuming your files are relatively small and your not saving much time.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a file in Isolated Storage is basically a file write operation. It is similar as how you will access a normal file and read write to it in normal operating system. in your scenario if you are sure that you need to update 5th line out of 10 lines, you will read line by line using stream reader and will use stream writer to update the specific line that you want to update. You do not need to re-write all content again and again.

On the other hand if you just want to add new content you can just append it to end of file. You may find this link useful http://goo.gl/IKii5